# How to make WPF Window cross 4 screens?

Tags: wpf

I have Four monitors with my PC,Is there any way to make a WPF window display cross four screens and maximized?

Answer (score 1):

I'd like just to complete Mark's answer. Actually the answer is no you can't and it is a windows limitation that only allows to maximize on one screen. However you can have a non maximized window stretched across multiple screens.

A more WPF approach would be something like this:

```
this.WindowState = WindowState.Normal;
this.Top = SystemParameters.VirtualScreenTop;
this.Left = SystemParameters.VirtualScreenLeft;
this.Width = SystemParameters.VirtualScreenWidth;
this.Height = SystemParameters.VirtualScreenHeight;
```

However I don't really know how it will behave when stretching across windows arranged in T or L shape.

Answer (score -1):

Yes, add a project reference to System.Windows.Forms and then add this to your MainWindow class:

```
protected override void OnInitialized(EventArgs e)
{
    base.OnInitialized(e);

    // get extents of all windows
    var left = System.Windows.Forms.Screen.AllScreens.Min(screen => screen.Bounds.X);
    var top = System.Windows.Forms.Screen.AllScreens.Min(screen => screen.Bounds.Y);
    var right = System.Windows.Forms.Screen.AllScreens.Max(screen => screen.Bounds.X + screen.Bounds.Width);
    var bottom = System.Windows.Forms.Screen.AllScreens.Max(screen => screen.Bounds.Y + screen.Bounds.Height);
    var width = right - left;
    var height = bottom - top;

    // resize main window accordingly
    this.WindowState = WindowState.Normal;
    this.Top = top;
    this.Left = left;
    this.Width = width;
    this.Height = height;
}
```